# Is there a Mockito equivalent way to expect constructor invocations like PowerMock.expectNew?

Tags: mockito, easymock, powermock

If it doesn't, does it exist on EasyMock?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) is intended as an extension of both EasyMock and Mockito.  From the horse's mouth: "PowerMock is a framework that extend other mock libraries such as EasyMock with more powerful capabilities."

In any case, there is no EasyMock equivalent to expectNew and neither is there one in Mockito, either - that's exactly the hole that PowerMock is trying to fill.  That being said, PowerMock is perfectly capable of doing this with Mockito.  Here is the sample from [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13):

> **How to mock construction of new objects**
>
> Use PowerMockito.whenNew, e.g.
>
> ```
> whenNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new
> IOException("error message"));
> ```
>
> Note that you must prepare the class
>   creating the new instance of MyClass for test, not the MyClass itself.
>   E.g. if the class doing new MyClass() is called X then you'd have to
>   do @PrepareForTest(X.class) in order for whenNew to work.
>
> **How to verify construction of new objects**
>   Use PowerMockito.verifyNew,
>   e.g.
>
> ```
> verifyNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments();
> ```